# Autre signification de "Fossoyeur" dans le nom du youtubeur "Le Fossoyeur de Films"?

Tags: sens, expressions, expressions-idiomatiques

[Le Fossoyeur de Films](https://www.youtube.com/user/deadwattsofficiel/videos?view=0&sort=p&flow=grid) est le nom d'un youtubeur Français qui parles de filmes. Je vois bien [le sens littéraire](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/fossoyeur/34725%5D) de "Fossoyeur", mais comment le comprendre on contexte? Est-ce tout simplement que le youtubeur ne se contente pas de simple revue de film mais va plus loin et offre des critiques perçant? Ou est-ce qu'il y a un autre sense du mot "Fossoyeur" qui est plus important dans ce contexte?

---

[Le Fossoyeur de Films](https://www.youtube.com/user/deadwattsofficiel/videos?view=0&sort=p&flow=grid) is the name of a French youtuber. I understand the [literary](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/fossoyeur/34725%5D) meaning of the word "Fossoyeur", but is there any additional meaning that the name is getting at? Is it just that beyond just reviewing films, the channel also criticises and digs into the movie genre as a whole? Or is there some other meaning of "Fossoyeur" that comes out in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Déjà, on peut dire que **[fossoyeur](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fossoyeur)** a un sens propre et un sens figuré. Au sens propre, il se rapporte à "celui qui creuse les fosses dans les cimetières", et au sens figuré, "celui qui participe à la disparition ou à l'anéantissement de quelque chose".

Sur la [page Wikipédia de l'auteur](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ois_Theurel), on peut lire que "son pseudonyme fait référence à sa volonté de « déterrer » des films oubliés ou de vieux débats". Je pense que c'est une explication suffisante.

Comment: Intéressant, mais du coup le nom n'est pas vraiment limpide. Le déterreur (pas très idiomatique) ou le nécromancien de films aurait peut-être été plus clair. "Fossoyeur" donne plutôt l'impression qu'il veut au contraire enterrer les films (ou les *achever*).